# How could I constantly add user input to a string without using lists, dictionaries, or sets?

Tags: python

I have a program that prompts the user for a guess on a guessing game, and I need the program to keep the values stored some how in order to prevent the user from guessing again.

For instance if a user inputs 'a' for the first guess and 'b' for the second, I need the program to store these and tell tell the user that they have already been used.

Guesses are always single characters. I am not allowed to use lists, dictionaries, or sets.

I know that i should concatenate the strings, but other than I'm clueless. I want to use a if statement or a function but not sure how to set those up.

I am also thinking that i need something like `variable += variable`. Any tips?

Comment: A set would be the correct solution here. Why don't you want to use one?

Comment: Are the guesses always single character?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm assuming it's a constraint put on them by a third party (*cough* teacher *cough*)

Comment: guesses are always single characters. not allowed to use sets, and i want to know how to do it in the simplest way possible.

Comment: I have tried "for" but i need that later the solution. The if that i made was set up incorrectly. Im not going to post the code because the teacher preferred that we dont, and i agree with them because then others can look it up and copy it

Comment: i never asked for people to post code. I did mention that i just wanted tips. I want to learn, not just copy peoples stuff because thats not gonna help in the long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should really be using a set. Here's how to do it with string concatenation though.

```
guesses = ""
guess = input("guess: ")
if guess in guesses:
    print("already used")
else:
    guesses += guess
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `set` and a simple `while-loop`:

```
guesses = set()

while True:
  guess = input("Please enter a guess: ")
  if guess in guesses:
    print("Sorry you have already guessed: %s" % guess)
  else:
    print("You guessed: %s" % guess)
    guesses.add(guess)
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter a guess:  5
You guessed: 5
Please enter a guess:  5
Sorry you have already guessed: 5
Please enter a guess:
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/F9QH/0)

Comment: Cant use sets. Thanks though

Comment: is has to be  string concantenation

Comment: If you wanted to use an `list` (python's arrays) instead of a `set` change the line:
`guesses = set()` to `guesses = []`
and the line: `guesses.add(guess)` to `guesses.append(guess)`

Answer (score -3):

If you are using C# you can use a StringBuilder (using System.Text;)

```
        StringBuilder guesses = new StringBuilder();

        guesses.Append("a");
        bool hasGuess = guessese.ToString().Contains("a");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using python!